# iptables ip rule fwmark doesn' t work

Tags: linux, ip, iptables, rule

I am trying to create iptables and mark it to ip rule.
Marking doesn't work.

```
# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local 
32762:  from all fwmark 0x2 lookup rteth4 
32763:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup rteth4 
32764:  from all to 93.xxx.xxx.xxx lookup rteth4 
32765:  from 93.xxx.xxx.xxx lookup rteth4 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default

# iptables -A INPUT -j MARK --set-mark 2

# iptables-save > /etc/network/iptables.up.rules

# iptables-apply

# iptables -L INPUT --line-number
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    MARK       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             MARK set 0x2
```

How can apply this: iptables -L INPUT --line-number
to use table rteth4?
And how to create iptables command that match localhost:port requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPTABLES doesn't have anything to do with routing tables, what do you mean apply iptables to use table rteth4.

To mark packets it better be in `PREROUTING` chain and preferably `mangle` table.

To mark a packet to match **localhost:23**, you can do this:

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -d localhost -p tcp --dport 23 -j MARK --set-mark 2
```